# Joint distribution of Gaussians after inner products

Tags: probability, statistics, gaussian

Suppose I have a $d$-dimensional multivariate Gaussian random variable $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{t}, I_d)$ ($I_d$ is the $d$-dimensional identity matrix) and $m$ vectors $\mathbf{w}_1, \mathbf{w}_2, ..., \mathbf{w}_m \in \mathbb{R}^d$ all normalized so that $\Vert \mathbf{w}_i \Vert_2^2 = 1$ for all $i \in [m]$. Then
$$
Y_i = \mathbf{w}_i^TX \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{w}_i^T\mathbf{t}, 1)
$$
can be easily shown based on properties of multivariate Gaussian random variables.

However, what will the joint distribution of $Y = [Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_m]^T$ be?

So far I have only managed to show that with $m = d= 2$ and $\mathbf{t} = \mathbf{0}$,
$$
Y = [Y_1, Y_2]^T \sim \mathcal{N}(
\mathbf{0}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
1&\mathbf{w_1}^T\mathbf{w}_2\\\mathbf{w_1}^T\mathbf{w}_2&1
\end{bmatrix}
)
$$
based on the results from O'Donell's Analysis of Boolean Functions (p.328, [https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~amnon/Classes/2016-PRG/Analysis-Of-Boolean-Functions.pdf](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Eamnon/Classes/2016-PRG/Analysis-Of-Boolean-Functions.pdf)).

And I guess with $X$ having mean $\mathbf{t} \neq \mathbf{0}$, the resulting $Y$'s covariance matrix should remain the same as what I had in the 2-dimensional case, only with its mean changing to $[\mathbf{w}_1^T\mathbf{t}, ..., \mathbf{w}_m^T\mathbf{t}]^T$, but I can't really extend my results to more general cases.

Does anyone have a better idea on this?